# I am having issues making bubbly button "bubble" javascript

Tags: javascript, css, express, npm-scripts, npm-start

the button appears and it is styled using CSS, that is ok however onClick it does not call the script, that is my best guess, have been trying to make it happen with no luck

I do not know if my script is not running ran debugging on package.json and it seems to have an issue however, it is beyond my knowledge at this point.

I do not know if my script is not running ran debugging on package.json and it seems to have an issue however, it is beyond my knowledge at this point.

I have tried updating package.json scripts: start however I think that the solution I tried was for another issue

```
["scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

`david@david-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~/Documents/Codecademy/Store-inventory/store-inventory$ npm run start
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js:2
`,CHAR_NO_BREAK_SPACE:"\xA0",CHAR_PERCENT:"%",CHAR_PLUS:"+",CHAR_QUESTION_MARK:"?",CHAR_RIGHT_ANGLE_BRACKET:">",CHAR_RIGHT_CURLY_BRACE:"}",CHAR_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET:"]",CHAR_SEMICOLON:";",CHAR_SINGLE_QUOTE:"'",CHAR_SPACE:" ",CHAR_TAB:"   ",CHAR_UNDERSCORE:"_",CHAR_VERTICAL_LINE:"|",CHAR_ZERO_WIDTH_NOBREAK_SPACE:"\uFEFF"}});var Lr=O((Ua,Pr)=>{"use strict";var ti=Xe(),{MAX_LENGTH:Or,CHAR_BACKSLASH:yt,CHAR_BACKTICK:ri,CHAR_COMMA:ni,CHAR_DOT:si,CHAR_LEFT_PARENTHESES:ii,CHAR_RIGHT_PARENTHESES:oi,CHAR_LEFT_CURLY_BRACE:ai,CHAR_RIGHT_CURLY_BRACE:li,CHAR_LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET:Ir,CHAR_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET:Nr,CHAR_DOUBLE_QUOTE:ui,CHAR_SINGLE_QUOTE:ci,CHAR_NO_BREAK_SPACE:fi,CHAR_ZERO_WIDTH_NOBREAK_SPACE:pi}=kr(),di=(e,t={})=>{if(typeof e!="string")throw new TypeError("Expected a string");let r=t||{},n=typeof r.maxLength=="number"?Math.min(Or,r.maxLength):Or;if(e.length>n)throw new SyntaxError(`Input length (${e.length}), exceeds max characters 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at Function.Module._preloadModules (module.js:754:12)
    at preloadModules (bootstrap_node.js:488:38)`
]

(https://github.com/ingdavidavila/Store-inventory)
```

Comment: Hi David, I think you questions relates more to npm and your setup, than it does to the Button. Your github link is not public, you might have linked a private repo.  It's hard for us to help you resolve this. though in general, a message like   `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` usually means the code is malformed. for example not closing an parentheses. `if (x1>x2  { console.log('c') }`  <- this is missing the closing `)` and would throw a similar syntax error.

Comment: My mistake I just made it public thanks for the response that way I can get some help

Comment: I'm able to run that repo locally without issue. Are you sure the faulty code has been pushed to that repo?  you could also try and run `npm install` from a terminal in the project root dir to make sure all packages are up to date.

Comment: The project runs, but the button on App.js does not trigger when clicked that is my issue then when I tried debugging on package.json is when I get those flags. and thanks for your time by the way

Comment: I see, I would recommend to have look at this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-button-functional-component-eectr?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:492-523).  There's no need for a separate 'script.js` file. the function and the button can all live in the same file. Instead of using a `addEventListener` to bind the function, you can pass it directly to the button `<button onClick={animateButton}>`,